# Unable to retrieve only folders from sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm unable to restrict the sharepoint search to only retrieve folders.

I'm running rest requests to the search api

https://(sharepoint url)/ian/_api/search/query?querytext='metatest3'

This retrieves only the folder that is on this collection but when I use

https://(sharepoint url)/ian/_api/search/query?querytext='metatest3 and IsContainer:1'

This doesn't retrieve the folder and no results are found.

I'm perplexed because when the first API call is returned I have

```xml
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
    <d:Key>IsContainer</d:Key>
    <d:Value>true</d:Value>
    <d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the REST API below to search only folders.

```
https://(sharepoint url)/ian/_api/search/query?querytext='metatest3 contenttypeid:0x0120*'
```

Or

```
https://(sharepoint url)/ian/_api/search/query?querytext='metatest3 IsContainer:true'
```

Comment: thank you for some reason all of the examples had and in the syntax, took this out and it works